# Creating a virtual nic with Python

Tags: python, networking, virtualization, nic

I'd like to use Python to create a virtual nic (like a bridged networking interface in a Virtual Machine).  The virtual nic would be assigned a unique DHCP address.

I'd like to be able to perform this action on Windows (unknown versions) using Python.  Is this possible with any current library?